# Out of memory error and 100% CPU usage in Java web application with jTDS

Tags: java, jdbc, memory-leaks, jtds, thread-dump

I am getting `OutOfMemoryError` in my web application.
When I analysed thread dump i found one blocker thread and stack trace is :

```
Finalizer 
Stack Trace is: 
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.releaseTds(JtdsConnection.java:2024)
- waiting to lock <662301fc> (a net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection) owned by "default task-204" t@896
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.close(JtdsStatement.java:972)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.close(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:707)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.finalize(JtdsStatement.java:219)
at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(System.java:1270)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:98)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:34)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:210)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None
```

Details stack trace :

```
default task-204 
Stack Trace is: 
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:850)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:731)
- locked <5bc15901> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:477)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:114)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.peek(ResponseStream.java:99)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.wait(TdsCore.java:4127)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.executeSQL(TdsCore.java:1086)
- locked <51eb98a0> (a net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsCallableStatement.executeMSBatch(JtdsCallableStatement.java:165)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeBatch(JtdsStatement.java:1051)
- locked <662301fc> (a net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeBatch(WrappedStatement.java:1077)
at com.XXX.MyDao.myMethod(MyDao.java:102)
```

On line number 102 of `MyDao.java` I am executing `callableStatement.executeBatch()`

I am using `jtds-1.3.1` for connection to database.

I analysed  thread dump using http://fastthread.io

Image for the same:

[image]

After restarting my application it works fine.

You can read about finalizer thread from [here](https://blog.fastthread.io/2015/11/20/thread-dump-analysis-pattern-leprechaun-trap/).